# JqGrid not dispatching beforeSubmitCell?

Tags: jqgrid

After reading documentation and googling once again and having not success with the dispatching of the beforeSumitCell event I have decided to post the question here. Here is the definition of my grid:

```
$(this).jqGrid({
    url:dataUrl,
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['Semana', 'Fecha', 'Precio D', 'Precio E'],
    colModel:[{name:'week',index:'index1', editable:false,width:100},
          {name:'date',index:'index2', editable:false, width:90},
          {name:'priceD',index:'index3', editable:true, width:90},
          {name:'priceE',index:'index4', editable:false, width:90}],
    rowNum:53,
    autowidth: true,
    rowList:[53],
    pager: jQuery('#pager1'),
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    editurl:"clientArray",
    onSelectRow: function (id)
    { 
        if(id && id!==lastJQGridSel)
        { 
            $(this).jqGrid('restoreRow',lastJQGridSel); 
            $(this).jqGrid('editRow',id,true); 
            lastJQGridSel=id; 
        }
    },
    beforeSubmitCell  : function(rowid, name,val,iRow,iCol)

    {
        alert("beforeSubmitCell called");
    },
    caption:"Modality prices"
});
```

Could anybody guess why it is not firing? Event calling stack says this event can be used with cellSubmit setting 'clientArray'. And it will fire only for a cells wich editable flag is set to true. In my case priceD.

To try to fire the evnet I just click on a cell for the priceD column and enter a value and hit enter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid supports three [editing modes](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs#editing): inline editing, form editing and cell editing. You use [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) which is part of inline editing, so to don't call the callback function [beforeSubmitCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) which is the part of the cell editing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight. I did not notice that the editRow command had a callback for "after saving". Thanks.